# How to fetch data dynamically on each "Tab" click?

Tags: visualforce, jquery, tab, repeat

I have a scenario where in a VisualForce page, there are multiple tabs with some repeating values. On clicking each tab, data needs to be fetched dynamically.
Currently I am implementing the tabs using JQuery tabs.

For Eg:

```
<apex:page controller="xxx">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();  

    function onclick() {
        j$("#tabs").tabs();               
    }  
</script>
<apex:form id="frm1>
.
.
.
.
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat value="{!objList}" var="obj">
            <li><a id="tablink" href="#tabs-{!obj.id}" >{!obj.name} - {!obj.id} </a>                            
            </li>                        
        </apex:repeat>                    
    </ul>    
    <apex:repeat id="repId" value="{!objList}" var="obj" >                    
        <div id="tabs-{!obj.id}" >                        
            <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="sch" id="dataTabPanel" >
                <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Scheduled Visit Mapping" id="sch"> 
                    <apex:outputPanel id="op1">
                        <apex:outputLabel styleClass="c1">Name : </apex:outputLabel>{!obj.name}
                        <apex:outputLabel styleClass="c1">ID : </apex:outputLabel>{!obj.id}
                         .           
                         .
                <apex:tab label="Tab2" name="Scheduled Visit Mapping" id="sch"> 
                    .
                    .
                    .
            </apex:tabPanel>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Question:

I want to fetch data dynamically if a tab is clicked, by passing `obj.id` value to my controller. Please suggest using current approach or any other approach to implement this design.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update based on @Victor comments**

Added `onclick` method as below:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!objList}" var="obj">
    <li><a id="tablink" href="#tabs-{!obj.id}" onclick="testTabClick();">{!obj.name}- {!obj.id} </a>                            
    </li>                        
</apex:repeat>
```

Javascript function:

```
function testTabClick() {
    alert('Test1');
}
```

I tried with `actionfunction` for the Javascript method. It was not working. So I tried a basic Javascript method, but this is not triggering either.
Is there anything I am missing here ?

I also tried to use the Javascript remoting method. That worked fine, but with the limitation that RemoteAction method has to be static, I wont be able to access the class instance and its data created on pageload. Is there any way to solve this ?

**Solution:Added the following code**

1. `onclick="testTabClick('{!obj.id}');"` to `<a href..>`
2. `<apex:actionFunction action="{!getCurrentObjId}" name="testTabClick"  oncomplete="onclick();" >
        <apex:param id="objId" name="currObjId" value="" />
       </apex:actionFunction>`
3. Apex controller:
   `public void getCurrentObjId(){
      String currObj = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('currObjId');
    }`

Reference link: [Parameter passing using Javascript+actionFunction in visualforce](http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com/2011/06/parameter-passing-using.html?showComment=1431111607587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a controller method to get list of data and pass object Id using two methods
1) Using actionfunction and a parameter inside it
2) Using RemoteAction.

In both ways finally you will get a javascript method name. Call that javascript method onclick of tab.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried both of your approaches but I am still facing some issues with it. I edited my post with the update as per your comments. can you please check if I am missing anything.

Comment: Is there any error coming on browser console?. Please try like  - <a id="tablink" href="#tabs-{!obj.id}" onclick="return testTabClick();">{!obj.name}- {!obj.id} </a>. Also return true at the end of testTabClick() method

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I am able to resolve the issue finally. My bad I used "Alert" instead of "alert". I updated the post with the solution..